# "parochial interest" vs "parochial concerns"

Tags: meaning

Please tell me the meaning of "parochial" in the two sentences below:

1. The future of the Labour party is too important to be a matter of merely parochial interest.
2. Beyond parochial concerns, there are breathtaking battles ahead.

Comment: In what way/s do you find dictionary definitions inadequate?

Comment: In dictionary several  meaning esit and don't know which one is correct for two sentence.

Comment: You don't show any research at all. Our sister site, ELL, is for basic questions, but they also expect a modicum of research.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

meaning is "of limited or narrow-minded interest".

Comment: If that's a quote from somewhere, please indicate that it is a quote and reference it correctly.

Comment: Reference is :https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parochial